# why does doOnComplete execute immedeatily regardless of delay()

Tags: rx-java2, rx-android

I was just writing some sample code with `takeUntil` -

```
final Observable<Integer> stopper = Observable.just(1)
            .doOnComplete(() -> view.append("second stream complete"))
            .delay(500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

return Observable
            .range(0, 10)
            .zipWith(Observable.interval(100, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS), (item, interval) -> item)
            .takeUntil(stopper)
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .subscribe(view::append);
```

So ideally, the stopper emits after 500ms and terminates the second observable, which it does. BUT the `doOnComplete` prints immediately.
[image]

As I understand from the documentation - `delay` shifts the events forward in time - including the complete event. So why would this happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look in the source code of the [just](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/blob/45cc53db6d9211a8fc2f62b8167ed54d4f7fda83/src/main/java/io/reactivex/internal/operators/observable/ObservableScalarXMap.java#L247) (namely ScalarDisposable in ObservableScalarXMap.java) operator you will see that all it does is emits one `onNext` event with the provided value and immediately after that it emits `onComplete` event. In your example you've put `doOnComplete` before `delay` operator - that's why `doOnComplete` gets called immediately and after that the  event is delayed for 500ms.

Answer (score 1):

According to [documentation](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/just.html), `Observable.just()` completes immediately - so message will be printed out right now. 
If you want the message be printed after delay you should modify it like that

```
Observable.just(1)
        .delay(500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
        .doOnComplete(() -> view.append("second stream complete"))
```